# Как из AS3 определить, в каком браузере открыта флэш?

Tags: браузер, actionscript

Пробовал вот такой вариант. В принципе больше не нашел вариантов.

```
        try
        {
            userAgent = ExternalInterface.call("window.navigator.userAgent.toString");

            var browser:String = "[Unknown Browser]";
            var OS:String = "[Unknown OS]";

            if (userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") != -1)
            {
                browser = "Safari";
            }

            if (userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") != -1)
            {
                browser = "Chrome";
            }

            if (userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1)
            {
                browser = "Internet Explorer";
            }

            if (userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera") != -1)
            {
                browser = "Opera";
            }

            if (userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("macintosh") != -1)
            {
                OS = "Mac";
            } else {
                OS = "Windows";
            }

        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {

        }
```

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался уже с таким?

P.S. По большому счету, это нужно, чтобы сделать нормальную анимацию под разные браузера. В одном браузере одни задержки, и анимация красивая становится. В опере, например, приходится ускорять таймеры, чтобы не было рывков в анимации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript запускается в изолированное среде и не имеет абсолютно никакого представления о внешнем окружение. Однако он может вызвать внешний скрипт на выполнение и получить результат его работы. К примеру, JavaScript.

В свою очередь, JavaScript тоже не имеет представление об окружающей его среде, только к информации, которую ему может предоставить браузер. А в браузере есть только одно место, откуда можно получить примерные сведения, это `window.navigator.userAgent`.

Такова политика безопасности браузеров, поэтому, кроме вашего варианта, больше способов нет.

Ну, еще можно посмотреть [тут](http://javascript.ru/blog/Plush-Grigorij/Funkciya-opredeleniya-brauzera-ego-versii), как лучше организовать проверку (синтаксис JS и AS в этом плане будет одинаковый).

```
var bName = function () {
                if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > -1) return "ie";
                if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > -1) return "firefox";
                if (ua.search(/Opera/) > -1) return "opera";
                if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > -1) return "chrome";
                if (ua.search(/Safari/) > -1) return "safari";
                if (ua.search(/Konqueror/) > -1) return "konqueror";
                if (ua.search(/Iceweasel/) > -1) return "iceweasel";
                if (ua.search(/SeaMonkey/) > -1) return "seamonkey";
                return "undefined";
            }();

switch (bName) {
    case "ie" : IEInit(); break;
    case "firefox" : InitFF(); break;
    case "opera" : InitOpera(); break;
    case "chrome" : InitChrome(); break;
    ...
    case "undefined" : InitDefault; break;    
};
```